# Can I damage screen (Nexus 7) by having it turned on and not change for longer periods of time?

Tags: nexus-7, screen, physical-damage

I wanted to use an app called TimeWise to have a timer ticking and showing how much time is left in a time-boxed task. However, I am not sure, if having the screen turned on like this (even with very **low brightness**) for **25 minutes** without changing its content other than the counter, cannot damage it. These 25 minutes can be repeated for 4-8 hours. It is likely, that I will change the content of the screen from time to time, so this might be helpful, but I am not sure. Does anyone know if my concern is pertinent, or it is no problem for this type of screen? The device I'm using is Nexus 7 2013 version. Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about screen burn-in?

Comment: Talking about any kind of damage, I dunno, what can happen. But yeah, the only thing I know of is something, that I would understand as burn-in, although this is the first time I hear the phrase.

Comment: I guess in that case I must have ruined most of my tablets, using them as eBook readers on train (and whereever) – sometimes reading for hours (until "battery low"). But alas, they're still working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Izzy, I thought about it this way too, but then - I don't know how other, but when I read on the device, I scroll the text pretty often, which makes the pixels, that are showing white change to black etc., so I thought, that this might be a little different, than leaving the screen unchanged for half an hour repetitively,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Both versions of the Nexus 7 use IPS LCD displays, which are not vulnerable to burn-in or other detrimental effects from displaying a fixed graphic.

Burn-in in currently used display technologies is a problem limited to organic light emitting diode (OLED) displays, such as those used on the Samsung Galaxy S3 and S4.  The Electroluminescent compounds used to make these displays degrade as they are used (resulting in reduced brightness over time), thus displaying a fixed graphic will result in some parts of the screen wearing at a different rate than other parts.  Compounding this issue is that different colours of OLED degrade at different rates (blue degrades fastest, followed by green, then red).  Here's an example of what this looks like.  The burned-in sections will be permanently darker than the rest of the screen.

[image: picture of OLED burn in]

Comment: I would add that LCD screens are not subject to burn-in; they can suffer from a similar, but not permanent, condition "transient image persistence" - as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in#Plasma.2C_LCD_and_OLED_displays)